# How to put default string in Jtextpane and make it uneditable in java

Tags: java, swing, command-line, cmd

Before all, I have a **Jtextpane** that takes text from another **Jtextfield**.
and I want the **Jtextpane** to have a default string i.e. whenever I run my program it shows up at the beginning with some properties:

1. To be uneditable (user cannot delete it or edit it at all)
2. When the user enters some text in Jtextfield it appends that text to it (I already did a method that appends the text in Jtextfield to the Jtextpane)

To be clearer it is the same as cmd in windows which prints "C:\Users\username>" as the default string and takes commands from the user after ">" sign.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHck6.jpg)

Comment: sometimes a look in the API helps https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html There you could see that the _JTextPane_ inherits the method `setEditable()` from the _JTextComponent_.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I've used `setEditable()` but it makes the "whole" Jtextpane either editable or not. I think you got my question wrong I want to make a part of it editable and the other not. Is that even possible?

Comment: Consider using a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Answer (score 1):

The following was designed for a `JTextField` but it should also work for a `JTextPane`. It uses a `NavigationFilter` to control where the `Caret` can be positioned.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NavigationFilterPrefixWithBackspace extends NavigationFilter
{
    private int prefixLength;
    private Action deletePrevious;

    public NavigationFilterPrefixWithBackspace(int prefixLength, JTextComponent component)
    {
        this.prefixLength = prefixLength;
        deletePrevious = component.getActionMap().get("delete-previous");
        component.getActionMap().put("delete-previous", new BackspaceAction());
        component.setCaretPosition(prefixLength);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias)
    {
        fb.setDot(Math.max(dot, prefixLength), bias);
    }

    @Override
    public void moveDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias)
    {
        fb.moveDot(Math.max(dot, prefixLength), bias);
    }

    class BackspaceAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JTextComponent component = (JTextComponent)e.getSource();

            if (component.getCaretPosition() > prefixLength)
            {
                deletePrevious.actionPerformed( null );
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Prefix_", 20);
        textField.setNavigationFilter( new NavigationFilterPrefixWithBackspace(7, textField) );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Navigation Filter Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work then check out [Protected Text Component](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/protected-text-component/) for a more complex solution that allows you to protect text in multiple locations.